# mysql request from two tables when one is empty

Tags: php, mysql, database, request, left-join

I have two tables. And my request return me zero rows if my second table is empty and first - isn't... How can I solve this problem?

Table: users

```
id username name   email
1  myuname  myname myemail@domain.com
```

Table: accounts

```
customerid phone params
1          +1111 NULL
```

My sql request is below:

```
SELECT 
A.phone, 
A.params, 
U.email, 
U.username, 
U.name 
FROM `account` A, `users` U 
WHERE A.customerid = U.id LIMIT 1';
```

The request above return zero rows if my account table is empty and users table isn't...
How can I solve this problem? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT 
    A.phone, 
    A.params,
    U.email, 
    U.username, 
    U.name 
FROM
    `account` A LEFT JOIN `users` U ON A.customerid = U.id
LIMIT 1
```

A LEFT JOIN will select all rows from the first table and only the rows on the second table that matches. If there is no match, U.email, U.username and U.name will be NULL.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `LEFT JOIN` your tables.

```
'account' a LEFT JOIN 'users' u ON u.id = a.customerid
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT 
    A.phone, 
    A.params,
    U.email, 
    U.username, 
    U.name 
FROM account a 
LEFT JOIN users as u ON u.id = a.customerid;
```